# MSSCCI compliant git client

Tags: windows, git

I am looking into a Microsoft Source Code Control Interface (MSSCCI) compliant git client. Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Visual Studio Plugin for 2008 and 2010 available on CodePlex: http://gitscc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [visualgit.io](http://visualgit.io/). It is a MSSCCI compliant git client, released under GNU GPLv2.